# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when making a request

Tags: mysql, node.js, linux, database, ubuntu

I use mysql on ubuntu and I set up everything but then when I try to make a request it shows error like this

```
    {
      "code": "ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR",
      "errno": 1045,
      "sqlMessage": "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)",
      "sqlState": "28000",
      "fatal": true
    }
```

I use Knexjs to connect my database I guess thats the problem?

//knexdb.js

```
const knex = require('knex')({
client: 'mysql',
connection: {
  host : 'localhost',
  port : 3306,
  user : 'personal_user',
  password : 'personal_password',
  database : 'database_name'
}
```

});

module.exports = knex`

I tried doing `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root';` already and I checked that my "root" already has a password but it didn't work at all

Comment: Get out of the habit of using root for anything except system administration.

Comment: @stark I actually created my own user but somehow it gave me an error and says it was denied in root